# Juniper MX80 throughput

Tags: juniper

I did not work with juniper mx routers and i want to use a juniper mx80 as edge router, we have 2-3x BGP Full table and our traffic ~10-15g traffic, Is juniper mx80 a stable router? How much bps pps is able to handle?
Is juniper mx80 RE able to forward attacks easily to customer if port is not congested?

Answer (score 5):

3 full tables on a MX80 sounds like very bad idea. They are notoriously bad at keeping RIB and FIB in sync due to limited CPU power, which means that if you have a lot of BGP updates (for example if the link to one of your full table providers gets disconnected) you will see a lot of blackholing going on for a long time. It can take over 30 minutes for FIB to get in sync with the RIB, and you'll be dropping traffic most of that time.

I also doubt you'll be able to put 2 or 3 full tables in memory, since that's pretty limited as well, with no options to expand it.

The box is End-of-Sale (and maybe even End-of-Life by now), it sounds like a pretty bad idea to use them the way you mention it.

As for throughput, you can look up those specs on the Juniper website, but typically Juniper hardware is able to do line rate traffic on ports, that would be the least of my worries with this model.